# meaning of "pain clinic"

Tags: expressions

What is exactly a **pain clinic** as used in

> The hospital is holding/having a pain clinic on Tuesday night for anyone interested in learning how to deal with chronic pain

Does it refer to

1. a place that offers medical help with pain management (independent of a large hospital or as part thereof), or
2. an occasion when a doctor gives medical advice to patients suffering from pain on a one-on-one basis in one of those rooms in a hospital, or a meeting during which a doctor gives advice to multiple people at the same time on matters relating to pain management?

Comment: Have you googled *pain clinic*?

Comment: I have, but I have also looked up the many meanings of "clinic." Since there are many combinatorial possibilities in the language, I'd like to know how the particular expression would be naturally interpreted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delivery of medical care varies considerably around the world, so let's see if the sentence itself offers any clues to the meaning of "pain clinic"— whether it is

- a) a location where pain-management is discussed, or
- b) a one-on-one between patient and practitioner, or
- c) a group session in which a  practitioner speaks to an assembled audience.

> The hospital is holding/having a pain clinic on Tuesday night for
>   anyone interested in learning how to deal with chronic pain.

We can eliminate a) since *locations* are not **held**. We don't **hold** locations. We hold *events*.

**for anyone interested** in this context (an announcement) suggests the clinic is open to all comers (at least until the occupancy limit of the room is reached), though the word **anyone** could also refer to an individual:

> I'm leaving this old bike out on the curb for anyone who wants it.

We couldn't really say "for **all** who want it".

But we could have said:

> The hospital is holding/having a pain clinic on Tuesday night for
>   **all** who are interested in learning how to deal with chronic pain.

"For anyone interested" is just a sloppy colloquialism here, the author of the sentence trusting that the audience will understand that the clinic is open to anyone and everyone.

Comment: You are saying "pain clinic" in my original example means "a group session in which a practitioner speaks to an assembled audience," aren't you? Does the phrasing in this particular sense strike you as unusual in American English?

Comment: Yes, a group session. There's nothing unidiomatic about the sentence in AmE ("holding" preferred over "having").

Comment: @Apollyon it's perfectly natural to "hold" a clinic. See for example:   ["Baseball to **hold Lions Hitting Clinic** during November"](http://saintleolions.com/news/2017/10/24/baseball-to-hold-lions-hitting-clinic-during-november.aspx) and many others.